# Error from server (BadRequest): container velero is not valid for pod node-agent-

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, backup

I'm getting frequent errors when I want to use `kubectl exec deployment/[deployment]`. This happens with Velero, a Kubernetes backup tool, but I assume that it happens with other deployments as well, Velero is just the only one I'm using with `kubectl exec` using a deployment reference. I'm only seeing the error when using the deployment reference and never when I use a pod reference. The error appears after a week or so and before it occurs I execute the command multiple time without issues and after it appears once it fails every time.

The command is `/velero backup create operations-test-1 --from-schedule full-backup --wait` and the error is

```
Error from server (BadRequest): container velero is not valid for pod node-agent-4p4dl
```

so `kubectl -n velero exec -i -c velero deployment/velero -- [command]` fails every time after that and `kubectl -n velero exec -i -c velero pod/velero-abcdef123 -- [command]` succeeds.

Strangely if I restart the daemonset `node-agent` with `rollout restart` which is also a part of Velero and the only other workload in the namespace the issue disappears. There's nothing in the logs and no probes fail. All pods the deployment and daemonset are green.

I'd really like to understand why `kubectl exec` behaves this way.

The alternative to use the pod by retrieving the name with `kubectl get pods` and parsing the output would be acceptable (it's not great!) if there weren't edge cases like getting a terminating pod.

My current approach is to use

`kubectl run backup --image=$(kubectl -n velero get deployment/velero -o yaml  | yq e '.spec.template.spec.containers[] | select(.name == "velero") | .image' -) --restart=Never -i --rm --command -- [command]`

but that fails due to missing permission. That issue can be fixed by specifying a service account with `--overrides`, but I'm a bit concerned that I'll have to recreate basically everything that is in the deployment and that I'd just be so great if one could use the description that is a deployment to perform tasks.

In an ideal world Velero - a backup tool with Kubernetes explicitly in mind - would give any recommendation how to do backups on Kubernetes, but the docs only give the commands.